# PHP - preg_replace how to add an extra "]" and an extra "["

Tags: php

Is there any way to do this with preg_replace or other php code?

I have a string that looks like this:

```
[[10],[11],[2],[3],[5],[1],[10],[15],[20],[21],[14],[16],[17],[6],[9],[4]]
```

I want to display like this:

```
[[10,11],[2,3],[5,1],[10,15],[20,21],[14,16],[17,6],[9,4]]
```

So I replaced the "],[" part with `str_replace`

```
$xy1 = str_replace('],[', ',', $xy1);
```

And now looks like this:

```
[[10,11,2,3,5,1,10,15,20,21,14,16,17,6,9,4]]
```

But I need to add an extra "]" after every second number and an extra [ after every second comma ex.:

```
[[10,11],[2,3],[5,1]
```

Comment: Is the source json data by any chance?

Comment: What do you mean? You want to see the json data source code?

Comment: What I wanted to know is why would you prefer to work on string data, instead of say an array of values, and your data looked like json. Ie, the string could have been converted into an array and worked on, or worked on before being output as json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of possibilities:

The string is valid JSON, whether it was intended to be or not, so you can decode it, chunk the resulting array and re-encode it.

```
$result1 = json_encode(array_chunk(array_column(json_decode($string),0),2));
```

If you are producing the string in your previous code via `json_encode` it would be much better to just use `array_chunk` at that time, but if it's coming from some other source you obviously can't do that.

For this specific string, it may be less cumbersome to pair the numbers with a regex.

```
$result2 = preg_replace('/(\d+)\D+(\d+)/', '$1,$2', $string);
```

Or a combination of both ways, extract all the numbers and then chunk and encode.

```
preg_match_all('/\d+/', $string, $numbers);
$result3 = json_encode(array_chunk($numbers[0], 2), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help, extract the nested array values and then group them by pairs.

```
$newArray = array_chunk( array_column( $array, 0 ), 2 );
```